# Bind json that has list of object to a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding, modelbinders

I want to bind this json:

```
{

        "DataPeriodId": 1,
        "MarketerId": 2,
        "MarketerTitle": "mehrdad",
        "CreditValues": [
            {
                "Title": "twelve",
                "CreditTypeId": 1,
                "Value": 2500000,
                "CreditId": 3,
                "HasMax": true
            },
            {
                "Title": "test",
                "CreditTypeId": 2,
                "Value": "",
                "CreditId": "",
                "HasMax": true
            },
            {
                "Title": "pouya",
                "CreditTypeId": 3,
                "Value": 1564564,
                "CreditId": 7,
                "HasMax": false
            },
            {
                "Title": "jafar",
                "CreditTypeId": 4,
                "Value": 0,
                "CreditId": 9,
                "HasMax": false
            },
            {
                "Title": "saeed",
                "CreditTypeId": 5,
                "Value": 0,
                "CreditId": 10,
                "HasMax": false
            }
        ]

}
```

To this object:

```
public class MarketerCredit
{
    public int DataPeriodId;
    public int MarketerId;
    public string MarketerTitle;
    public List<CreditValue> CreditValues;
}
public class CreditValue
{
    public int CreditId;
    public int CreditTypeId;
    public decimal? Value;
    public bool HasMax;
}
```

in mvc.net.

But when pass the json to  action all member is null.
This is my action:

```
   public void EditMarketerCredit(MarketerCredit marketerCredit)
        {


        }
```

So i write this:

```
public void EditMarketerCredit(List<CreditValue> CreditValues,int DataPeriodId,int MarketerId,string MarketerTitle)
```

When separate the members all thing is ok.
How can i bind the json to model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add get and set for property:

```
public int DataPeriodId{get;set}
```

You added write just

```
public int DataPeriodId
```

And Mvc can not bind.

Answer (score 1):

According to your json, you need a root object encapsulating `MarketerCredit`

```
public class RootObject
{
    public MarketerCredit MarketerCredit { set; get; }
}
```

BTW: your json contains a line `"CreditId": "",`, So type of `CreditId` should be *string*

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement your own custom model binder and then register it when the application starts. Here's a [walkthrough](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) explaining how to achieve this.

But, if you want to avoid customizing the MVC Pipeline you will need to create a new class/model that exposes a property called `marketerCredit` of type `MarketerCredit`, you can name this model whatever you like

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MarketerCredit marketerCredit{get;set;}
}
```

then modify your action method like this...

```
public void EditMarketerCredit(MyModel myModel)
{
}
```